# Integrate function as a power series

Tags: integration, power-series

The problem:

> Integrate the following as a power series, find the RoC: $$\int x^2\ln(1+x)dx$$

My work:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\int[ x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}]dx$$
$$=\int[\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n}]dx$$
$$=C + \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n+3}}{n(n+3)}$$

Which I believe to be correct. The book however has the following answer:

$$C + \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{\color{red}n}\frac{x^{n+3}}{n(n+3)}$$

I've worked through the problem several times, but I don't see where the change in power for the $(-1)$ comes from. I feel like I must be overlooking something simple/fundamental about the problem.

RoC is obviously $1$ either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in the book is wrong. Your answer (and your solution) is correct.

Comment: Well it's nice to know that I'm not totally hopeless. Thanks for the confirmation!